# Canvas stop repaint on focus lost

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, box2d

I'm creating a game using Box2D.

When I click on the canvas and press the "tab" key, canvas repaint stops.

Any idea about this?

[Game demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/box2d/pinball)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be behavior that's built into the library. The `canvas` element has a `blur` event listener on it, so when it loses focus, the render loop pauses.

If you need tab functionality in your game, you might consider appending some focusable elements into the canvas element, and managing focus among those.